# Constant wifi drops on El Capitan

Tags: network, macos, wifi, internet

I use a 2015 Retina MBP (13inch) and have been experiencing wifi disconnections since I have upgraded to El Capitan. I am now using 10.11.5 and the problem remains. I am experiencing wifi dropouts on this computer only. My wife uses an old 2011 MacBook Air with El Capitan 10.11.5 and has no disconnections. My other devices iPhone + iPad Mini are also on the same wifi network and do not experience any problem. I have tried many of the usual suggestions such as: throw previous wifi preferences to trash, created new wifi profile/location with google dos, changed MTU to 1453 and disabling Apple Wifi Direct Network (awdl0) and nothing seemed to do the trick. I cannot seem to find a proper answer anywhere but have seen many people experiencing the same problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

side note: the only annoying "fix" is to manually renew my DHCP lease or turn off / on my wifi which takes longer to get back online. If i do nothing, it will get back online after a longer period (less than 1min).

Comment: I fixed a similar problem by changing the device that acts as the DHCP server on the LAN.

Comment: Hi Nikita, could you walk me thought that by explaining how you proceeded? What exactly did you change?

Comment: I have two devices capable of serving DHCP: an all-in-one box provided by the ISP and another wireless router running OpenWRT. What I did is disable DHCP server on the box and set up a new one on the router. Then I set up the box to treat the router IP as the DMZ host on the network (since all routing and firewall would be handled by the router anyway). Now all connections go through the new router and my mac doesn't "forget" its IP.

Comment: Thank you Nikita. It seems quite straightforward and easy. I guess I should invest in a new router. Thanks for the heads up.